# Обращение к дочернему елементу через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Нужно достать все дочерние элементы span'а. Или если получится, то сразу достать последний элемент:

```
<span id="searchResults_links">
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink active">1 </span>
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">2 </span>
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">3 </span>
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">4 </span>
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">5 </span>
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">6 </span>
    ...
    <span class="market_paging_pagelink">673 </span>
</span>
```

Вроде бы правильный код, но вместо заполненого списка, при принте, получаю пустой. Вот код:

```
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find('span', id = 'searchResults_links').find_all('span', class_ = 'market_paging_pagelink')
    print(pagination)
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text())
    else:
        return 1
```

Пробовал обращаться напрямую, но тогда эти элементы вообще не находит:

```
pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'market_paging_pagelink')
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пожалуйста заменить этот фрагмент кода:

```
pagination = soup.find('span', id = 'searchResults_links').find_all('span', class_ = 'market_paging_pagelink')
```

На этот, должно помочь:

```
    pagination = soup.find('span', {'id' :'searchResults_links'}).find_all('span', class_ = 'market_paging_pagelink')
```